Getting null for <system.web> when accessing via C#
I'm trying to get the timeout value in the following from web.config:
<!-- Majority of xml left out for brevity -->
<configuration>
    <configSections>...</configSections>
    <system.diagnostics>...</system.diagnostics>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms timeout="1" /> <!-- Trying to get this value -->
        </authentication>
    </system.web>
</authentication>
</configuration>

I'm using this C# code to start off with. My goal is to first access system.web:
var value = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("configSections"); // null
var value1 = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.diagnostics"); // SystemDiagnosticsSection
var value2 = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web"); // null

value and value2 are both null, but value1 is an instance of SystemDiagnosticsSection.
Why can I access system.diagnostics but not system.web?

Thanks to @Yong Shun's comment, I worked it out based on the suggested answer:
var authenticationSection = (AuthenticationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/authentication");
var timeout = (int)authenticationSection.Forms.Timeout.TotalMinutes;

